# What are the best unconditional bounds for the discrete moments of $\zeta'$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, moments

I heard this morning through the app Researcher about the following article by Scott Kirila: arXiv:1804.08826v2 in which the author proves under RH that $J_{k}(T)\asymp_{k}(\log T)^{k(k+2)}$, where the discrete moment $J_{k}(T)$ is defined as $\frac{1}{N(T)}\sum_{0<\Im(\rho)<T}\vert\zeta'(\rho)\vert^{2k}$ where the sum runs among the non trivial zeros of $\zeta$.
This settles affirmatively a conjecture by Gonek and Hejahl for the case of $k$ being a positive integer, while the aforementioned authors expect such a relation to be fulfilled for any real positive value of $k$.

Before this achievement, Millinovich proved that $J_{k}(T)\ll_{k}(\log T)^{k(k+2)+\varepsilon}$ for any $\varepsilon>0$, the lower bound $J_{k}(T)\gg_{k}(\log T)^{k(k+2)}$ having been proved by Millinovich and another author, both under the assumption of RH.

My question is thus: which are the best currently known unconditional lower and upper bounds for $J_{k}(T)$?

Comment: What is the meaning of $\sum_{0<\Im(\rho)<T}\vert\zeta'(\rho)\vert^{2k}$ ? Under the RH it is $\int_C \zeta'(1-s)^k\zeta'(s)^k\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}ds$

Comment: Just a sum over the zeros located in the upper half plane, more precisely in the domain $\{s\vert 0<\Re(s)<1\wedge 0<\Im(s)<T\}$.

Comment: ... Why do we care of it ? Why this sum specially can be estimated ? What is the difference with $\int_C \zeta'(1-s)^k\zeta'(s)^k\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)}ds$ ? It is you who is asking on MO about their "best currently known bounds" so you are supposed to have some clues about the answers.